# Implement a bar with some buttons in android

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm having some difficulties to reach a way of implementing an layout that i want for a android project. I have to make a layout like this:

[image]

This bar is at the top of the android screen over a map of google and each icon are a button. The map is already in the layout at this time.

Whats the simple way of doing this with android layout?

After that and not so important at this time, after click each button i have to open a rectangle with some options to fill (text boxs and dropdown lists) but i know that i can do this with a alert dialog. Is this the best way for doing this part?

Regards for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Action Bar, and overlay it on top of the map.

To enable overlay mode of the action bar, you have to create a custom theme and modify some values:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

More information on this in this [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use third party libraries for this. **ActionBarSherlock**  is the library which you can use.

Here's a link [Click here to download](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html)

and for tutorial follow this [link](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/).

thanks

Comment: This also works but i prefer to use the above solution. Thank you!